# Constant application crashes on 4S running 6.1.2

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

I have a brand new iPhone 4S, running 6.1.2, consistently crashing applications from core services like iMessage to Evernote and Tweetbot. Phone calls can be sent and received, but experience 1-3 second 'black outs' where I can't hear the conversation. These happen on approx 2-5 minute intervals. I've restarted, hard restarted (hold down buttons for 10 sec) and resynched to iTunes.

Useful context:
iCloud configured 
Exchange email configured via Zenprise

I'm glad to do every rational troubleshooting step, I just don't know enough about logging to imagine where to start on this one.

Comment: Why do you think your iCloud/Exchange configuration is related to the issue? Did you try a full recovery via iTunes and then run without the Exchange setup for a few hours?

Comment: I'm not at all sure of the correlation, though thought either - do to complexity / interconnectivity of them - could spark an 'ah ha' moment for a reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a funky one. The result -- something wrong with my iCloud synchronization. It was causing Notes to have hundreds of thousands of copies that resulted in NoMemory crashes.

Not your textbook issue.. but keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Do a device backup (iCloud or iTunes or both). Restore the device. If a core app is crashing after force quitting the app and doing a hard rest this is the most likely fix.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've done so once already but I'm willing to give another shot. Could you elaborate on how to confirm a problem exists and/or its fixed?

Comment: If I restore the same image, why wouldn't I be reinstalling whatever error I'm running into? Thanks for supporting my curiosity here.

Comment: If you've already done a full restore, then that probably won't fix the problem. You could try doing a restore WITHOUT restoring from backup (and then rebuild your phone manually). Better yet, if there is an Apple Store nearby, make a Genius Bar appointment before doing anything. They can do a behavior scan with a special app they have that will tell them if there is an underlying hardware issue. If you've already restored and are under warranty there is a chance they will just give you a new phone. At the very least they will be able to confirm if it's ultimately a hardware or software issue.

Comment: I've done restores without using from backup three times now. Within a few days I'm back to crashing. App goes to black screen then dies. Apple Store follow up to come...

Comment: Yes, definitely a faulty piece of hardware in there. Good luck!